# How to query for data in API responses using for-loops and append results to list?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm getting deeply nested data from an API request and I need to check if the most inner data is equal to a certain string.

This is an example of an item in `response["contents"]`:

```
{
"file-name": "Some-clients-name",
"file-number": "some-index",
"assistants": [
    {
        "name": "Some-assistants-name",
        "id": "de5c-21e4-ae01"
    },
    {
        "name": "Some-assistants-name",
        "id": "1d6d-4973-b248f"
    },
    {
        "name": "Some-assistants-name",
        "id": "bd3f-482a-gffc"
    }
],
"involved": [
    {
        "contact": {
            "name": "Some name",
            "id": 6562
        },
        "role": {
            "main-role": "client",
            "side-role": "prosecutor"
        },
        "under-involved": [
            {
                "contact": {
                    "name": "Some name",
                    "id": 424t
                },
                "role": "legal protection service"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "contact": {
            "name": "Some name",
            "id": 339f
        },
        "role": {
            "main-role": "opponent",
            "side-role": "defendant"
        }
    }
],
"legal areas": [
    "Contract law"
],
"clerk": {
    "name": "Some name",
    "id": "4fsd-fwe4278-b07df"
},
"keywords": [],
"status": "ACTIVE",
"reason": "coaching"
```

}

The script should loop through every item in `response["contents"]` and check if `["under-involved"]["role"] == "legal protection service"`. If true, the key/value pair "file-number": "some-index" of that item should be appended into an empty list. If false, the same key/value pair should be appended to another empty list.

So, the script should loop through every record and sort those into two lists, one containing records with legal protection service involved, and one without.

I tried to work with try/except here, because not every record contains data representing "under-involved", which caused my prior code to crash.

```
headersAuth = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + refreshToken(refresh_token),
    "accept": "application/json"
}

legalservice_true = []
legalservice_false = []

for i in range(0, 10):

    url = f"https://app.labrog.de/v1/awwkten?page={i}"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headersAuth)

    for record in response.json()["content"]:
                
         try:

             for involved in record["involved"]:

                 if involved["under-involved"]:

                     for i in range(0, 5):

                        if involved["under-involved"][i]["role"] ==   "legal protection service":
                                
                            legalservice_true.append(record)
                    

         except:
                
              legalservice_false.append(record)
```

The problem here is that every record can have multiple "involved"s, and the script decides after every single loop through the "involved"s if it should append the record to a list. I end up having the same record in the lists multiple times in the end.

Every record from `response["contents"]` should only appear once in an output list, and never in both lists, regardless of how many `["under-involved"] == "legal protection service"` it contains. If the script finds the value "legal protection service" in the record, the key/value pair "file-number": "some-index" of that record goes into the `legalservice_true` list. Otherwise it should go into the `legalservice_false` list.

This is a sample of the desired output:

```
legalservice_true = [{"file-number": "334/21"}, {"file-number": "337/21"}, {"file-number": "382/21"},...]
legalservice_false = [{"file-number": "352/21"}, {"file-number": "388/22"}, {"file-number": "391/22"},...]
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what your desired output is. If there are 3 "involved"s and 2 have ["under-involved"]["role"] == "legal protection service", what should the output be? It would be good to show sample input AND the associated desired output.

Comment: @Joe thanks for the hint, hopefully i made it clearer this time

Comment: So are you saying that `response["contents"]` is a json object, and it may have zero, one, or multiple `key: value` pairs with the key `"involved"`?

Comment: or will there only be at most one key `"involved"`, with a value that is a list of objects, and by 'multiple "involved"s' you just mean that that list might have more than one item?

Comment: When you say 'loop through every item in response["contents"]', do you actually mean 'loop through every item in response["contents"]["involved"]'?  Because response["contents"] is a json object - its items are key: value pairs, e.g.  `"file-name": "Some-clients-name"`

Comment: Again, what would help would be for you to explicitly write, "The desired output on the input above is:" (followed by the exact output you want from your example.

Comment: @Joe sorry for being unclear here. response["contents"] is a json object I get when making an API request. response["contents"] is a list of items of the format that is previewed in the question. There will always be at most one key: value pair with the key "involved", with a value that is a list of objects. With multiple "involved"s I mean that this list might have more than one item. Every item in "involved"s will definitely have the keys "contact" and "role" in it, and it MIGHT have the key "under-involved" too.

Comment: If this is the case, and the value of "under-involved" is "legal protection service", then the key/value pair "file-number": "some-index" of that record should be appended into the legalservice_true list. If the value of "under-involved" is something else, or if there is not "under-involved" at all, the "file-number": "some-index" of that record should be appended into legalservice_false list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
legalservice_true = []
legalservice_false = []

legalservice = False
for involved in contents['involved']:
    if 'under-involved' in involved:
        for under_involved in involved['under-involved']:
            if ('role' in under_involved and 
                under_involved['role'] == 'legal protection service'):
                legalservice = True
                
this = {"file-number":contents["file-number"]}
if legalservice:
    legalservice_true.append(this)
else:
    legalservice_false.append(this)
```

If it doesn't meet your needs, please update your post to describe the way in which it failed.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks a lot!